# How to remove all before for empty list?

Tags: python, list

Can not figure out how to produce the result with function:

```
remove_all_before([],0) == []
```

I tried using `bool()`, `len()`, and `if not`, but nothing worked for me

```py
from typing import Iterable


def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) -> Iterable:
    for x in list(items):
        if items:
            if items.count(border)>0:
                if x == border:
                    return(items)
                else:
                    items.remove(x)
            else:
                return(items)
        else:
            return(items)
```

Comment: Can you describe the function a bit more

Comment: Which input you want for "BEFORE"? a index (position), element or what ?

Comment: The function wants to remove all elements before the given border, for example
remove_all_before([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) == [3, 4, 5]
remove_all_before([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 2) == [2, 2, 3, 3]

Comment: @AlbertWijaya Wouldn't it be better to use slicing to remove everything before the index of that number? I'm thinking of something like `items = items[items.index(2)::]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'm thinking, since the `border` is an `int` but not the index of the list, using the `index()` method of the give list to mark where to slice the whole list (*as I've said in my preliminary comment*) . It would of course find the first element in the list and include all the repetions of `4`.

```py
>>> def remove_all_before(items, border):
...     return items[items.index(border)::]
...
>>> a_list = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4]
>>> remove_all_before(a_list, 1)
[1, 2, 4]
>>> remove_all_before(a_list, 4)
[4, 5, 1, 2, 4]
>>> remove_all_before(a_list, 2)
[2, 4]
```

---

##### EDIT:

Thanks for awarding me, @AlbertWijaya , you are too kind. But I think the other solution with the `if border in items: ...; else: ...` by @Wonka is more complete.

It's exactly what I was proposing from my comment with the condition in case the `border` is not inside the list. I cannot be sure cause I didn't check, but it probably was posted even before my answer

Comment: Similar to my answer that he downvote, your solution will crash if border not in list

Answer (score 1):

With default return of complete list, if element `border` not in list:

```
def remove_all_before(input_list, input_border):
    if input_border in input_list:
        return input_list[input_list.index(input_border):]
    else:
        return input_list  # return entire list if border not contained

remove_all_before([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
```

Prints: `[3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Unvote if you want but this is the solution you looking for, it works and other answer tried to copy my  answer

Comment: Now upvote same solution but that will crash if border is not on list

Comment: Unlike [duplicate answer explaining the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72828356/5730279), this solution is more robust having a default return in case `border` is not found (thus my edit and upvote).

Comment: Thanks @hc_dev, edited now, but i will remove this probably

Answer (score 1):

To complex code with nested if-statements and obsolete list-construction, duplicated return branches.

Hard to spot a logical bug, so I would clean first:

#### Clean the code first

```
def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) -> Iterable:
    for x in list(items):  # no need to construct a list from list
        if items:  # 1st condition (use and)
            if items.count(border)>0:  # 2nd condition (use and)
                if x == border:   # 3rd condition (use and, flip to remove as consequence)
                    return(items)  # remove the default branch (duplicate 1 of 3)
                else:
                    items.remove(x)
            else:
                return(items)  # remove the default branch (duplicate 2 of 3)
        else:
            return(items)  # un-indent (without else) as default return (duplicate 3 of 3)
```

#### Then spot the issue

```
def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) -> Iterable:
    for x in items:  # items is a list already, no need for list()
        if items and items.count(border) > 0 and x != border:  # combined nested if-conditions to one (with a little flip)
            items.remove(x)
return items  # return default (duplicates removed)
```

Considerations:

- Shouldn't it stop removing, one **before** `x == border` reached ?
- Shouldn't it return immediately, once `x == border` is met ?
- Instead `items and items.count(border) > 0` you can also use `border in items` to test if the list contains the `border` (and thus is non-empty)
- If `border` is not in list at all, you don't need to loop and remove, do you?
- Wouldn't a `while` loop be suitable to iterate and remove **until** the element `border` is found ?